# Execute main() from test source with a command line gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a StubApplication class with `main()` method that starts up a WireMock stub.

StubApplication sits under `src/test/java`. And I can run it through Intellij

What I'm looking for is a way to start both main app (that part works fine with `gradle bootRun`) and the StubApplication from the command line with gradle.

Something like

```
task stubRun(dependsOn:bootRun) {
    mainClassName = 'StubApplication'
}
```

Except that ^^ doesn't work.

It's a Spring Boot 2 app if that makes a difference

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html

Comment: Your task `stubRun` must be of the task type `JavaExec` to execute a Java application.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to comments I figured this issue has nothing to do with spring boot. Something like the following works just fine

```
task stubRun(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: ['testClasses']) {
   classpath sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
   main = "StubApplication"
}
```