# Gradle Run throwing "Error: Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

Project Structure is:

```
src
---main
---test
       ---java
              ---ExecutionClass
                                ---TestNGMain.java
```

build.gradle is like:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'test.java.ExecutionClass.TestNGMain'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'test.java.ExecutionClass.TestNGMain'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs= ['src/test/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs= ['src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

gradle build - works fine

gradle run - throws error "Couldn't find or Load main class"

Comment: could you post the `package` statement for `TestNGMain.java`

Comment: package ExecutionClass

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852959

Answer (score 1):

By default the application plugin only considers the [`main` source set as the application code](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)  for distribution. If you really want to run code in a test source set, then one option is to include the test sources in the main (bad idea)

```
sourceSets {
    main{
        java{
            srcDir("src/test/java")
        }
    }
}
```

The `mainClassName = "<package-name>.<class-name>"` in your case `mainClassName = "ExecutionClass.TestNGMain"`

Another way is customize the `main` distribution to include the test files.

Answer (score 0):

Running a class from src/test is possible using JavaExec, instead of the `application` plugin:

```
task runExample(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: "compileTestJava") {
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = "com.example.Example"
}
```

The purpose of the application plugin is not just to run a class, but to package an application so that it can be deployed, shipped to customers, etc. and it would usually not be desirable to have all the test stuff included at runtime.

So it is a generally bad idea to try to use the `application` plugin to run anything that is in `src/test`